# What GAPPS do I need for Ressurection Remix 5.7.4 by aditya?

Tags: rooting

Idk if I really need a different GAPPS for ressurection remix cause I flashed pico GAPPS. I need to know if I flashed the GAPPS or I flashed the wrong GAPPS.

Comment: Size depends on how much space you still have in `/system`; it's the architecture (ARM/ARM64/x86) and Android version that actually matters.

Comment: ok thanks for your answer, i just get how it works.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends. You can choose any flavour, what you need to be careful about is to select the right CPU architecture and Android version. Different flavours of GAPPS are just packages with a different number of Google apps. So you can download the whole Google Suite or just a few basic apps like the phone, Play Store or calculator.